# Tag for command line interface

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I believe that question such as [Key Mapping in Command Line Mode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30411/121) need an appropriate tag and I couldn't find one already in the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tag nomination: [command-line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Tag nomination: [text-interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-interface)

Answer (score -2):

Tag nomination: [terminal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal)